# Rails background video on landing page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video

I am trying to put a video background on my landing page but I am getting a routing error?

No route matches [GET] "/videos/propose.mp4"

This is what I have done so far:

Here is the video path app/assets/videos/propose.mp4

config/application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/videos"
```

landing.html.erb

```
<%= video_tag "propose.mp4", autoplay: :autoplay, loop: :loop, mute: :mute, class: "video" %>
```

application.css.scss

```
.video {
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%; left: 50%;
 z-index: 1;
 min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I have never used a video on a rails site so I feel like I might be missing a step. Thanks!

Comment: Did you restart server after adding to application.rb ?

Comment: Also try restarting the spring process if you've already restarted the server

Comment: I was able to get video in a rails app for the first time based on this question. However, when I start my server and go to localhost, it plays. But mysteriously it doesn't play if I open a second chrome tab and go to local host. I don't know why? Also, the video isn't in the background, but the whole screen is video (and everything else that should be there is missing - although it's in the HTML, just doesn't appear anywhere on screen).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sajan... of course it was something simple. I just had to restart my server.